# Get the current version of the package

Tags: c#, .net-standard

Follow code:

```
public static string GetVersion()
{
    //for .NET Standard 2.0
    //return FileVersionInfo.GetVersionInfo(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location).ProductVersion;

    //for .NET Standard 1.2 - write the version number manually.
    return "1.0.0";
}
```

I'm trying to get the package version **.Net Standard 1.2**, because the `FileVersionInfo` class does not exist.

Any solution for version 1.2?

Answer (score 1):

For .NET Framework:

```
using System;
...
string ver = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetupInformation.TargetFrameworkName;
```

and for .NET Core:

```
using System.Reflection;
using System.Runtime.Versioning;
...
string ver = Assembly.GetEntryAssembly()?.GetCustomAttribute<TargetFrameworkAttribute>()?.FrameworkName;
```

Output:

```
.NETFramework,Version=v4.5.1
.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.0
```

Answer (score -1):

Was looking around for how to get Package Version.
You question is correct, just missing the namespaces.
code below is full namespaced for System.Diagnostics.FileVersionInfo and System.Reflection.Assembly

To note, if possible concern, this is running form .Net Standard 2.0.3

```
var package_version = System.Diagnostics.FileVersionInfo.GetVersionInfo(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location).ProductVersion;
```